# Is possible only bind a list on Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've this class:

```
public class Last5Match
{
        public List<Match> HomeTeamMatches { get; set; } = new List<Match>(5);
        public List<Match> AwayTeamMatches { get; set; } = new List<Match>(5);
        public string HomeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeamName { get; set; }
    }
```

that is implemented in this way:

```
Last5Match _lastFiveMatches = new Last5Match();
```

I don't need to declare a list like this:

```
List<Last5Match> _lastFiveMatches = new List<Last5Match>();
```

'cause in this object I've two list. What I need to to is bind the object:

```
 public Last5Match LastFiveMatches
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastFiveMatches;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastFiveMatches = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

on my Datagrid and access to the property of the list `HomeTeamMatches` and `AwayTeamMatches` simply adding something like:

```
<DataGrid 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding LastFiveMatches}">
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="5" Binding="{Binding HomeTeamName[0].Nameoftheproperty}"/>
```

is this possible? 'cause actually I get no value displayed, if instead I replace as ItemSource `LastFiveMatches.HomeTeamMatches` I get this working but I can access only to the properties of HomeTeamMatches

Comment: i think theres an interface you need to implement IEnumerable maybe or bind the grid to the list property grid1.datasource = last5matches.list1

Answer (score 1):

you could make a new property called TotalMatches

```
public class Last5Match
{
        public List<Match> HomeTeamMatches { get; set; } = new List<Match>(5);
        public List<Match> AwayTeamMatches { get; set; } = new List<Match>(5);
        public string HomeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeamName { get; set; }
        public List<Match> TotalMatches
        {
           get{ return HomeTeamMatches.Union(AwayTeamMatches).ToList(); }
        }
    }
```

then bind your grid to TotalMatches

Comment: but in this way how can I know which matches are of HomeTeamMatches and AwayTeamMatches?

Comment: add a property on Match for IsHomeTeam?

Comment: @fantozzi instead of managing two seperate lists your object should have a boolean (or a enum) to specify the "type" of the object.

Comment: this will complicate the things

Comment: @fantozzi How, should that complicate things? You have a ``Match`` that has a indicator what kind of ``Match`` it is, thats the natural way to do it.

Comment: var match1 = HomeTeamMatches.Select(M => new(){
    MatchProperty1 = M.MatchProperty1,
   ....
  IsHomeTeam = true

})

Comment: @fantozzi Additionally, I wouldn't recommend doing a ``Last5Match`` class in the first place, this should only be done by a query and that query than should be the DataGrids ItemsSource. So assuming, you somewhere have a list with all Matches ``var allMatches = new List<Match>(); var last5Matches = allMatches.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Where(x => x.HomeTeamName == "name1" && x.AwayTeamName == "name2").Take(5); DataGrid.ItemsSource = last5Matches;`` end of story - now you have a list of 5 matches, with "name1" vs "name2", ordered by date

Comment: the linq query is useless in my case, I've a method that return 5 matches for a specific team, I need to save this matches in a specific list, so I've organized this two list inside an object but as I can see it's not possible in wpf doing what I want to do.